# Rails - seeding data with has_many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a seed file with the following code within it:

```
300.times do
  # create the customer
  customer = Customer.create([
    {customer_type_id: '1'}
  ])

  # create an address for the customer
  address = Address.create([
    {city: Faker::Address.city, country: 'UK'}
  ])
  postcode = Postcode.create([
    {value: Faker::Address.uk_postcode}
  ])
  name_number = NameNumber.create([
    {value: Random.rand(495)}
  ])
  street = Street.create([
    {value: Faker::Address.street_name + " " + Faker::Address.street_suffix}
  ])
  state = State.create([
    {value: Faker::Address.uk_county}
  ])
```

This works fine. I had hoped, however, to be able to do the following:

```
address = Address.create([
  {city: Faker::Address.city, country: 'UK'}
])
address.postcode = Postcode.create([
  {value: Faker::Address.uk_postcode}
])
```

Where I have created the address in the first line, and I am creating the postcode for the address in the second line. This, however, generates an error.

Could anyone suggest how I can do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: As requested, the error generated is:

```
rake db:seed
rake aborted!
undefined method `postcode=' for #<Array:0x007f9df1f26818>

Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Could you specify what error it generates?

Comment: I've edited to add the error.

Comment: The lines are following each other exactly as written - perhaps I am wrong in thinking that the "address = Address.create" line sets the address variable to the newly created object? Do I need to set this separately afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing an array to `create`, which creates one object for each hash of attributes in the array and returns the resulting array of objects. Since you're only creating one object at a time, simply remove the square brackets around your hash of attributes (and even the curly braces if you want) and it should work correctly:

```
address = Address.create(city: Faker::Address.city, country: 'UK')
```